# How do I use mysqlimport?

Tags: java, mysql, database, mysqlimport

Here is the command I am running using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` in Java:

```
mysqlimport --fields-terminated-by=, --lines-terminated-by="|" --local 
--user=u --password=p DatabaseName 
txtpath
```

Here is the error I get:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "mysqlimport": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
at databaseCommunication.UploadThread.run(UploadThread.java:66)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
... 5 more
```

It seems like the problem should be that mysqlimport.exe is not installed or is not installed in the correct place, but I have tried downloading the mySQL utilities from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/5.6.html and from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/utilities/.

In order to make sure the problem was not that it could not find the file at "txtpath," I typed the full path into the command prompt, and the correct file was opened, so the error is definitely referring to mysqlimport.exe.

Googling my problem, the only threads I've been able to find refer to something called "Sqoop" which I am not familiar with, and they usually recommend downloading the mysql utilities.

For more context, I have been using BCP to upload data from a txt file to a sql server database, but now I need to do the same thing with mysql.  If there is any way to use BCP (I'm pretty sure there isn't) or something else to bulk upload data from a local file I would be open to hearing that as well.

**EDIT:**
I am using Windows 8 on a remote desktop.  I have manually added mysqlimport.exe to the PATH environment variable and it still gives the same error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows, then try putting `mysqlimport.exe` as the command rather than just `mysqlimport`. If that still does not solve your problem, make sure that 'mysqlimport.exe' is in your PATH environment variable.

Comment: I am on Windows, and I have edited my answer to include specifics about my operating system.  I changed it to `mysqlimport.exe` and manually added the path to the PATH environment variable as per [these instructions](http://superuser.com/questions/737542/how-can-i-add-a-program-path-to-the-windows-environment-variables-for-easy-comma).  Additionally, it appears that the mysql utilities were already in the PATH variable.

Comment: Can you try putting the full path to 'mysqlimport.exe' into the exec()?